# what is behind array_unique function in php?

Tags: php

Before asking this question,
I explored more but didn't get satisfying result.

People usually ask related to their problems in array_unique function. But, here
i want to know

how **array_unique** function works in php? And where can i see the inbuilt function definition?

Comment: See here how it works: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#2777

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: there are too many unknown things. I am not so experienced in php. Could you give alternate way to find working of array_unique function..
By the way very thankful n +1 for the link

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Why post an answer as a comment?

Comment: @maxterner: Either you want the internal implementation (which dev-null-dweller linked to), or you want some "alternate" approach. Which is it? And why do you need to know?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because I think this kind of question is off-topic here. Other thing is that I'm pretty sure, C source code is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit : i am solving some puzzle of multidimensional array and to find unique value...that's y this question came in my mind.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: The OP asked to see the inbuilt function definition, and that definition is in C as you have proved. Your comment is a perfect answer to the stated question. I don't see why it would be off-topic.

Comment: Basically, the link provided by @dev-null-dweller shows you how it works, specifically the section below the _"/* go through the sorted array and delete duplicates from the copy */"_ comment: it's a loop that checks for duplicates. The difference is that this is C-code: it's faster, and allocates and deallocates the memory in a way that you simply can't do with PHP...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is open-source, so if you are wondering about how part of it works, you can always check it here: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=summary

The more friendly site to browse/search in PHP source code is http://lxr.php.net/.

The whole magic behind `array_unique` is described here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#2777

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts and time